# Exporting QGIS polygon shapefiles to Trimble Juno or similar

Tags: qgis, shapefile, trimble

I am considering buying a Trimble Juno or similar hand-held field computer to assist with vegetation survey.  My main need is to be able to see on it shapefile polygons drawn on my home PC in QGIS.  I am told by a salesman that I would require to buy data collection software in order to be able to do this.  Is this necessary or is there an open source workaround?

Answer (score 1):

There is probably an easier way, but you can import OSM files into Garmin GPS:

http://blog.gravitystorm.co.uk/2007/01/07/osm-on-my-gps/

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mkgmap

And you can convert shp to OSM without much difficulty:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shp2osm

Come to think of it, I would imagine most GPSs could import GPX files, which can be created with QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

Does Juno still run on Windows? In that case gvSIG Mobile http://www.gvsig.com/en/products/gvsig-mobile?set_language=en is theoretically an option. However, the project is not especially active and getting Java for the Juno unit is not easy. I have done it so it is possible, though, and gvSIG Mobile is quite a feature rich software and it can read, write, and edit shapefiles.

Maybe you would like to consider some Android based device and Geopaparazzi http://geopaparazzi.github.io/geopaparazzi/.

Answer (score 0):

The Juno does run on windows, but if you have not heard of the trimble 3000, you should look into it. the 3000 has .5 meter accuracy when in static mode, and the juno has 2.5 meter accuracy at best in static mode. Now if you do get the r8/r10 Base/Rover system either one will have sub-centimeter accuracy. the down side is the 3000 is about 40% larger.